# How to save bit into sql?

Tags: php, sql

In my SQL database, I have a BIT column with a length of 2.

```
 `modulcheck` BIT(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
```

I want to send 2 as Integer and save it as BIT (should be 10). I don't know why but it automatically saves as 11 which is 3.

I am using execute function and right before it I have a `var_dump`. the item value is `int(2)`. I also tried string 10 but that also didn't work.

The default value is 0, so when it is changing to 11, it is not the default value.

```
var_dump($pvalues[":modulcheck"]);
$query->execute($pvalues);
```

The results of var_dump for `$query` and also `$pvalues`:

```
object(PDOStatement)#41 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(273) "INSERT INTO gph_menu(id, name, link, modulcheck) VALUES ( :id, :name, :link, :modulcheck) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = LAST_INSERT_ID(id), id= :id, name= :name, link= :link, modulcheck= :modulcheck" } 

array(6) { [":id"]=> int(40) [":name"]=> string(4) "test" [":link"]=> string(8) "test.htm" [":modulcheck"]=> int(2) }
```

Comment: Can you show your query? Are you using MySQL or something else?

Comment: Unable to replicate your issues in a DB fiddle -- https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uZ2QHuGCThwnCSwqQMZ7Ek/0, and its hard to see what you're actually doing, because you're not showing much code.

Comment: The code automatically created with a very complex stuff but I added the final query in the question.

Comment: in your code you have UNSIGNED, Shall I activate it? Here I see it is disabled.

Comment: and execute function comes from here:https://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: That's just a cast to display the value as integer (so converting it from binary to decimal).